# Visual Studio 2013 Add in development (it adds files to a project but not in source control)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-addins

I created an Addin for visual studio (2010, 2012 and 2013).
The purpose of this add in is to copy some sample files form sample folder to different MyPrettyCMS portal folders. During the operation, the addin make some modifications to files.

It works well BUT when the MyPrettyCMS Portal project is in a source control (TFS in my case) the files are not added to the source control, just to the project.

Do you know how I could also register new files in the source controller ?

Answer (score 0):

the cmd is:

```
tf add  myFOLDER\myFOLDER2\SRC_CODE.CPP program1.cs
```

you can make your addin to call this cmd to add files.

see more commands here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9yw4ea0.aspx